# TYPEORM migration issues Windows 11

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm struggling with migration issues on Windows. Does any one has a solution other than downgrade type or to 0.3.12 or something like that?

I ran all kind of migrations commands and there is no way to run them succesfully.

Comment: This is not answerable with the information provided. Please try to ask this question how you might ask a busy coworker. Make it succinct, include specific and robust details. I'd suggest taking a look at [ask] and [mcve]